# ng-change not triggering for second time when value updated with event.target.value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to reset value of `input:textbox` if the value entered is non-numeric. I'm using ng-change to validate the input. Refer the code below

```
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this.P)" ng-model="P" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Principle" />
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this.R)" ng-model="R" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Rate" />
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this.T)" ng-model="T" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Time" />
```

Note onChange function is getting called from all three textboxes.

The `onChange` function is as follows

```
$scope.onChange = function(n) {
      if (!$scope.isNumeric(n)) {
        event.currentTarget.value = '';
      }
```

**Issue**: The problem is that if I enter the same non-numeric alphabet twice the `ng-change` event is not triggered.

For example if the key `q` is pressed twice the `ng-change` will not trigger when the key is pressed for the second time.

See jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/vwmfbgy2/)

Additional question: Is there any better way to reset the value of the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `ng-change` is not firing again for same alphabet because you are updating the `currentTarget.value` but not the `ng-model`.

Suppose you enter d in the text box. Now `$scope.P = "d"`. Now `ng-change` will fire and you clear the text box, remember `$scope.P` is still `"d"`. Now if you enter `"d"` again `$watch` wont fire because previous value of `$scope.P is "d"`.

To resolve this update the model instead of currentTarget.value.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwmfbgy2/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use input type 'number' which is an inbuilt feature of HTML5. It allows only numeric values. You don't need the onChange function.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="P" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Principle" />
```

However, that comes with up/down arrows in the corner. You can hide them with CSS if you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you. This does fix the problem at hand, but I don't believe is a generic solution to the `ng-change` event not triggering the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `model` key along with `ng-change` and just update model value so it will automatically update your `input`

```js
angular.module('SimpleInterestApp', [])
  .controller('simpleCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.onChange = function(obj, modelKey) {

      var n = obj[modelKey];
      if (!$scope.isNumeric(n)) {
        obj[modelKey] = '';
      }
    };

    $scope.isNumeric = function(n) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    };


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="SimpleInterestApp" ng-controller="simpleCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this, 'P')" ng-model="P" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Principle" />
      <input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this, 'R')" ng-model="R" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Rate" />
      <input type="text" ng-change="onChange(this, 'T')" ng-model="T" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" placeholder="Time" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```